# webview not working onclick rather than the ontouch in android

Tags: android, webview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

i am newbie to android so just appologies if any issues come across for the asking questions regarding webview.if i try to swipe the webview it is working fine when implementing ontouchlistener using the answer from [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection/5742763#5742763). But i had a problem with onclick of hyperlink in the webview.if i try to click the hyperlink while i didn't get any appropriate page(onclick is not detecting).so please can you give any possible answer for this.

Comment: what do exactly want on hyperlink click?

Comment: @RaviKant when i try to click the hyper link while need to launch the appropriate link page.

Comment: what is happening now? click not detecting?

Comment: yes,onclick is not detecting over the webview if i try to implement ontouchlistener in webview.

Answer (score 0):

just check your ontouchlistener  because event not consuming overthere.except getting swipe value block ramaining all must return false.

Comment: yes i did like as return false when less than around the swipe range.but still i didn't get click event,